# Data is not getting shared between watchkit and iphone app

Tags: ios, apple-watch, data-sharing

I want to share data between iphone app and watchapp,following code I have used to share data between them:
//At iphone viewcontroller:

```
mydefaults=[[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.sample.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"];
[mydefaults synchronize];
NSString *msgStatus=[mydefaults objectForKey:@"msgStatus"];
```

//At iwatch side

```
appdefaults=[[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.sample.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults"];
[appdefaults setObject:@"read" forKey:@"msgStatus"];
[appdefaults synchronize];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked by following this video

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ts196U4xS4
```

Are you sure that you have turned on 'App Groups' for both iPhone part & iwatchkit extension ?
Also the app groups selected must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

My issue resolved by updating xcode to beta 6.2 version 5
and adding
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{@"msgStatus": @"unread"} reply:nil];
at watchkit side which was mentioned in previous answer which is deleted now dnt knw why :-( ,but I want to thank him(I dnt remember that persons name). plz post dat answer again.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are using the correct and the up to dated provisioning.

Comment: yes it is , and one more thing I am using xcode 6.2 beta version